# recyclerview get position of upper view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to get the position of `view` in `recyclerview` that currently is on the top of the screen? (Not the first view with position 0 but the view that is upper when i scrolls).
I need to check `if(upper != 0 && upper != 1)` do smth.

Comment: It's up to `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` not `RecyclerView` itself ... read the documentation of this class and I'm pretty sure that you will find proper method ...(maybe `getPosition(View view)`)

Comment: android:focusableInTouchMode="false"